# How to make delay Live Streaming (Using FMS + FMLE)?

Tags: amazon-ec2, video-streaming, flash-media-server

I've tried this [tutorial](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LiveStreamingAdobeFMS4.5.html) to provide HTTP live streaming from a camera, using FMS 4.5, and FMLE 3.2, and I succeeded.

Now I need to add a delay (1~10 minutes) on the HTTP streaming. My purpose is so that the client can view the video 10 minutes later than when it is first obtained from the camera

I'm using Amazon Cloud, specifically EC2 (include FMS 4.5).

Is this possible?

Comment: put thread.sleep(10000); while sending http request

Answer (score 0):

Set the server to have a DVR buffer. You can add the dvrinfo tag to the manifest.xml file and then specify the beginOffset to the delay you want.